Automatically Send an Email from Google Sheets using Data in Sheet Cells
I have a Google Sheet with Data from a Google Form. I would like to make an Apps Script that when a certain cell is edited in the Sheet, Apps Script will send an email response from me to an email in the sheet and include the message I wrote in a Cell. I have tried a number of codes and seem to be striking out. I had used this in the past but can not get the code to successfully run this time around in the new data sheet.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
See How do I ask a good question?

The function that sends email needs to run on an installable trigger rather than a simple trigger.
See my sendEmailNotification script for sample code.
